# Using Composite Key Or Unique Constraint to prevent row duplicate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table and data looks like this: This data is being mine from Archive.

[image: Table with duplicate row]

I am using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Values)` to get a single row. However, I would like to add a `CONSTRAINT` to the table to prevent duplicate inserts.

Because the data is Many to Many business rule, I figure I can either use a `Composite Key` comprising the `UserID` and all 4 additional columns.

I am looking at the following three options:

1. Should I use a CONSTRAINT comprising of all the columns below
2. Use a composite key comprising of the columns
3. Add a unique column (Clustered Index) and then use constraint on the rest of the columns.

However, using a composite I am still able to insert duplicate rows.

What is the better approach here?

Comment: Do you want to prevent more than one row per UserID? Or can there be multiple rows for a given userID, as long as they don't have the exact same value for all 4 columns?

Comment: Yes, I need to allow multiple rows but they cannot all have the same values as indicated in the example above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** A primary key with a unique constraint should be a good way to go.

You should definitely add a new column to serve as a primary key.  An identity column would be fine.  Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_1
   ADD id INT IDENTITY;

ALTER TABLE table_1
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_table_1
   PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

The reason for this is that it makes it easier to trace the row as an individual entity so you can more easily perform updates and deletes.  Plus, it's useful for 3rd normal form.

The primary key does not have to be a clustered index, btw.  Although a clustered index is created automatically by default for a primary key in SQL Server if there is not already a clustered index on the table.

Once you have a primary key, you can use a UNIQUE constraint for the other columns.  That's assuming that you are OK with the default system error messages.  If you need error messages more customized to your needs you will want to use an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER.

I would avoid a clustered, unique index with all the columns.  That will cause a lot of fragmentation and disk IO when you are inserting new records.  A non-clustered unique index would be OK, but then you've basically got a constraint at that point.

Comment: Neither surrogate keys nor single-column unique keys are *required* for third normal form.

Comment: That's true.  It is one way to perform third normal form, but not the only.  I updated my answer.

Comment: +1, even though I added my own post to discuss available constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (and probably best) way to do this is by placing some from of unique constraint on the four columns. There are three ways to do this:

- Primary key
- Unique index
- Unique constraint

The only difference between a primary key and the uniques is that uniques will allow nullable columns; the only difference between the uniques that I've ever found out is how they are defined (index vs. constraint), the underlying mechanics are the same. Since you get an index regardless, I'd stick with the index definitions.

Which to use depends on (a) are any of the column nullable, and (b) how the table will be used--that is, how best might it benefit from an index. Clustered, order of columns (taking cardinality into consideration), frequency of inserts and updates... the usual stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're optimizing for: insert performance vs. query performance, storage, complexity of queries etc.

Without any additional information, I'd recommend option #3: add a [surrogate PK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) column and enforce uniqueness of the other 4 with a separate constraint. Think for example of JOINs to other tables - the surrogate key will make sure you'll only have to include one column in your join predicate and not five.